How to make this Python function even faster, lists processing
I was doing a Hackerrank question (I already finished that test, I am just asking because I am curious).
Most of test cases were successful but a few said that it took too long, so I had to optimize my code. I assume it means that my solution works properly but it is too slow.
The idea is that you take 2 lists.

One original items (positive integers), items = [2, 1, 1, 4, 3]
A second query list (positive and negative integers), query = [-1, 2, -3, 1]

You have to process each query. If the current query is a positive integer, you just add it in the end of the items list. If the current query is a negative integer, it means that you have to remove the first apparition of that absolute value in the items list.
This is my code:
def process_orders(query, items):
    for q in query:
        if q > 0:
            items.append(q)
        else:
            q *= -1
            items.remove(q)

    return items

How can I make it faster?
Thanks
I removed some unnecessary extra loops. I even tried dictionaries, but it got worse.

numpy.array: allocate your items data structure before the while loop.

Appending can be a bit slow compared to direct access to an item based on its ID, but removing items in the middle of the list is generally expensive, especially for large lists : all item reference need to be moved (O(n) time -- while appending should be done in O(1)).

You can swap items so to remove them quickly from a list. A set can be used to track the location of items. This results in a O(1) implementation (with a significant constant). There is maybe a simpler solution (I heard that set/dicts are now ordered in recent version of Python).

don't items.remove(q) as you iterate

This problem is not meant to be brute forced. Removing from a list takes linear time; it is not the appropriate data structure.
This can be solved in O(N + Q) where N is the initial number of items and Q is the number of queries. We only need to output the final list of items at the end, so we can just maintain enough information to reconstruct the list in linear time at the end without ever having the complete list created in between queries.
We can use a dictionary of deques (for O(1) removal from the front and adding to the end), where the key is the item value and the value is a collection of times (in order) at which this value was added. To remove the first occurrence of an item, we can simply call pop_left on the deque corresponding to that value in the dictionary. To add an item, we just append the current "time" (the total number of elements inserted so far, including the inital ones) to the deque corresponding to the item value.
To construct the list to return, we can perform a counting or bucket sort on all the items by time of insertion. There are at most N + Q insertion times, so this takes O(N + Q).
from collections import deque, defaultdict

def process_orders(queries, items):
    elements = defaultdict(deque)
    for t, item in enumerate(items):
        elements[item].append(t)
    for query in queries:
        if query > 0:
            elements[query].append(t := t + 1)
        else:
            elements[-query].popleft()
    time_to_element = {time : value for value, times in elements.items() for time in times}
    return [time_to_element[t] for t in range(len(items) + len(queries)) if t in time_to_element]

Alternatively, you can append items to the list normally, but instead of deleting, keep track of how many times a particular value has been removed. When creating the final list, skip items that have not been encountered more than the number of times they have been removed.
def process_order(queries, items):
    removed_count = defaultdict(int)
    for query in queries:
        if query > 0:
            items.append(query)
        else:
            removed_count[-query] += 1
    result = []
    for item in items:
        if removed_count[item]:
            removed_count[item] -= 1
        else:
            result.append(item)
    return result

